# geduldig Twitter API Cannot figure how to use statuses/show/:id

Tags: python, twitter

I've been searching the doc and examples and yet cannot figure how to pass the id parameter to the statuses/show/:id endpoint.

response = api.request('statuses/show/:id', ????)

I'm asking this because I'm lost about it and there is no info about this :id type of request.

Comment: Use tweepy, it will make your life a lot easier and BTW id here refers to something like 2154778 which is unique for every user on twitter, Study tweepy you will automatically understand these small bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example:

```
response = api.request('statuses/show/:%d' % TWEET_ID)
```

where TWEET_ID is the id of the tweet you are showing.

Comment: I did, lately I figured out. Thanks a lot.